# TypeError: name.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

```html
<input id="name" type="number" placeholder="Name">

<script>
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    name.addEventListener('focus',function() {
        alert("Type your name");
    });

</script>
```

I have tried to clear cache, changed the browser, nothing helped. In jsfiddle the code works great, but in browser no.

Comment: maybe your js code is executed prior to your html

Comment: @Andreas however it is working ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ actually yes, with different from "name" name it is working even without window.onload

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, your script is getting executed before the html finish rendering. Add your code in onload callback so that it makesure that your  html loaded.

```html
<input id="name" type="number" placeholder="Name">

<script>
   window.onload = function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    name.addEventListener('blur',function() {
        alert("Type your name");
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Note**: Changed the event *focus* to *blur* to save myself from series of alerts.

Comment: @jack_snipe  This works because variable `name` is defined in the scope of a function, and therefore it doesn't collide with `window.name`.  Please also consider my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the variable name `name` to `aname` and it worked. It is generally advisable not to use variable names that might collide with Javascript keywords or predefined variables.  `window.name` is such a case